# VB silverlight for windows phone "The property 'background' was not found in type 'TextBox."

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

i am trying to set the property "background" on a textbox
but i am having this error :
`The property 'background' was not found in type 'TextBox.`

i guess that i have to import one more reference on xaml but i am not sure which one :S

any ideas ??

Comment: When an answer helps you, be sure to up-vote it and if it's the correct answer, be sure to up-vote and accept it. You're at 0% right now and that's a liiiiiiiitle low.

Comment: Guys i was wrong :
i didn't know that there was the tick button (accepted)
and it didn't allow me to upvote the answers because i had population less than 15

thank you for informing me :)
i vote every answer i ever had :)

Comment: In addition to what @EtherDragon said, most importantly, it's good for the community as a whole. Someone with a problem similar to yours can come and find your question and see that a resolution was found and it's clearly indicated. The strength of the this site is the users' willingness to help one another; it's a good balance of give and take.

Comment: @Demitris-Sapikas Glad to help, (both with your question and how best to use the site)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're setting this in XAML, the property name is case sensitive `Background` - it looks like yours is all lower case.

Comment: you're right ! it worked ! thank you !
i would never mind that the error would be something like that !